# SharePoint 2013 Workflow Email Notifications

Tags: workflow, email, notifications

I have three workflows set up that are linked to a SharePoint list created by an InfoPath form.  The first workflow is kicked off when a user submits the InfoPath form - an email is sent notifying me that the form has been submitted.  The 2nd workflow starts when I upload an attachment to the form - the original submitter is notified.  The 3rd workflow kicks off when the original submitter uploads a final attachment to the form and I get notified.  The first workflow works like a charm.  However, because I have "start workflow automatically when an item is changed" turned on for the 2nd and 3rd workflows, both emails are sent when the third step is done.  Is there a way stop the second workflow from starting when the third workflow starts?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a logic in workflow number 2 that has a "if" condition. Create a column in the list your workflow belongs to. Then at the end of workflow 2 set a state to that field. Put your the current logic of workflow 2 in a if condition that only runs if your new field is empty. If the "else" part of your workflow 2 is empty it will simply just run through it and therefore not send a email.

Use the same logic in workflow 3 but the only difference is that workflow 2 sets a value to a field and workflow 3 only runs if it is a value in that field.

If my answer is unclear - feel free to contact me for more information.

Comment: I already have an if statement - Workflow 2:  If Current Item: 2Item equals Yes, then email Current Item; Created By, then stop the workflow and log.  Workflow 3:  If Current Item: 3Item equals Yes, email me.

Answer (score 0):

I already have an if statement - Workflow 2: If Current Item: 2Item equals Yes, then email Current Item; Created By, then stop the workflow and log. Workflow 3: If Current Item: 3Item equals Yes, email me.

Comment: More detail. There are three sections in an Infopath form. User loads file in 1st section and clicks on Submit - sends out an Approval notification (1stworkflow). I load file in 2nd section and click on a check box and click Submit. This sends notification (2ndworkflow). Then user loads file in third section and clicks on check box in that section. This sends third notification (3rdworkflow).  Clicking on check box in the 3rd section "unchecks" box in the 2nd section so that 2nd workflow doesn't run again.  Problem: SharePoint list shows "no" for the 2nd check box when the process is complete.